# newline in text extraction from pdf

Tags: python, string, pypdf

I am coding a function about extracting text in pdf, I am also using the [pyPdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf) library. 
Extracting was okay. But I am encountering a couple of problems like it excluding the newline.

So I find a way to add a newline, so I have done this:

```
# Iterate pages
for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    # Extract text from page and add to content
    content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText()
    content = content.replace('. ', '. <br />')
    pages += content

# Collapse whitespace
content = " ".join(pages.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
```

The problem is even instances like this:

```
1. Apple
```

became like this:

```
1.

Apple
```

Which it shouldn't be. I just want to add newline on every end of a sentence.

Is there a way to check or determine when the sentence ends?
Or checking whether it is as numbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hackish solution is to perform replacement only if the full stop is not immediately preceded by a digit. Change the line `content = content.replace('. ', '. <br />')` to the following:

```
import re

re.sub(r'([^0-9])\. ', r"\1. <br />", content)
```

Comment: nice. But what if its instance is like this:
    
A.   ?

Comment: Then you can expand the regular expression to include capital letters as well `r'([^0-9A-Z])\. '`

Comment: No problem. It is not every day that you get to help Superman ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use re.sub()?

For a dot ended line and probably with some spaces, the pattern should be ".\s*$", i.e.,

```
import re
:

content = re.sub('\.\s*$', '. <br />', content)
```

Comment: What do you mean by re.sub(), 

and you mean like this?:
content = content.replace('.\s*$', '. <br />')

Answer (score 0):

pyPdf is great for some things, but not really good at text extraction. Have a look at the [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/) library. Or use a tool like pdftotext.

Comment: Sorry for asking, I am new to text extraction. But why did you say it is not good? Can pdfminer be also implemented in code or programatically like pyPdf? Because when I checked pdfminer, you just have to run it like `pdf2txt.py samples/simple1.pdf`. What I wanted is in code where I can modify it, I dont know. Sorry kinda new to pdf extraction.

Comment: @Superman: it's explained in the pyPdf docs for `extractText`. It doesn't guarantee that your text comes out in the right order etc... pdfminer on the other hand tries to analyse the layout, and based on position of characters, adds spaces (and newlines), puts the text in the right order and so on. And yes, pdfminer can be used as a library, see http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html

Comment: If ever I changed my code to pdfminer, will it affect a lot?